# Add options to several products at the same time

Tags: magento2, configurable-product-options

i've created some products and now I need to add several option on each of them. How can add to a list of products the created option ?

I've found how to import them into one product at a time, but is there an easier and fastest way to do this ? (I have like 300 products where I need to apply those options, so could take a while...)